# How to access properties into watch method in AlpineJS?

Tags: alpine.js

I want to access the properties of the component inside the watch method but it's not working. Apparently, this is not defined.
I use AlpineJS 3

Here my code :

```
<form x-data="config()" x-init="initModule()">
<input type="radio" value="one_date" x-model="type_date" /> 
<label >Option A</label>
                        

<input type="radio"  value="multi_date" x-model="type_date"/> 
<label  >Option B</label>
</form>

<script>
 function config(){
        return {
            type_date : '',
            date_option : {dateFormat: "d-m-Y"},
            initModule(){
                
                this.$watch('type_date', function(value){
                    console.log(this.date_option)
                 });
        }
}                   
                  
</script>
```

It's what i get in the console :
`undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you enter the anonymous function passed to *$watch*, the context changes and *"this"* refers to the *window object* (you can check this thing by adding a `console.log(this);` in the function).
To get around the problem we can use an arrow function which does not have its own context, so *"this"* will refer to the container object.

From Alpine 3, by adding an *init()* function to the object, you will no longer need to specify an *x-init* attribute: the *init()* function, if present, will be called automatically.

```html
<form x-data="config()">

    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="one_date" x-model="type_date" />
        Option A
    </label>


    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="multi_date" x-model="type_date"/>
        Option B
    </label>

</form>

<script>

    function config() {

        return {

            type_date: "",

            date_option: {dateFormat: "d-m-Y"},

            init() {

                this.$watch("type_date", (value) => {
                    console.log(this.date_option);
                });
            }
        };
    }

</script>
```